# Why does NumberFormatter drop monetary fraction digits in format()

Tags: php, currency, numberformatter

Why do the following two lines

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $fmt->format(12.34, NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
```

output `$12.00` ?

Comment: i am aware `$fmt->formatCurrency()` won't drop the digits, but i'd like to use `format()` because it allows to overwrite currency symbol via `$fmt->setSymbol()`.

Comment: For the love of god don't store money as a float, use a proper library like [moneyphp/money](https://packagist.org/packages/moneyphp/money) that won't straight up *lose* money due to floating point inaccuracy.

Comment: @Sammitch I know it, however I have to convert to them float in order to use NumberFormatter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the `NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` constant as the second argument to `format()`.

In the [predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#intl.numberformatter-constants) section of the `NumberFormatter` documentation, the constants are grouped under which methods they should be used with.

`NumberFormatter::CURRENCY` has a value of `2` and should be used when constructing the formatter, as you have done. A value of `2` in the `format()` function corresponds to `NumberFormatter::TYPE_INT64`.

You should just be able to call `format(12.34)` without a second argument.

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
echo $fmt->format(12.34);
```

Comment: thank you, I didn't notice i misuse the constant. Without second argument it indeed works as expected.